Odor in Antique Mahogany Chest of Drawers
I bought this beautiful antique mahogany chest of drawers that imparts a bad odor to anything fabric stored in drawers.
I am not sure what the odor is from but smells like stinky wood.  I want to put my clothes in it but can’t deal with odor. Any ideas of how to remove or neutralize the odor?

I’m voting to close this question because it isn't home improvement per the [help].

FYI, furniture questions are generally off topic here, aside from woodworking. Please take the [tour].

Have you tried an ozone bomb?

The permanent way to do it is to paint the inside. Silver paint is supposed to neutralise/mask smells. This is what the builders use to paint timber in a house after a fire. From experience, I can attest that it does work.

I’m not familiar with silver paint. Is it a type of paint?

Something you could try: Leave the drawers out in a open-air location where they won't get wet, so air can flow over them.
Smells are actually tiny particles of matter that come off an object. The matter may be from the object itself, or something active in the object because of water or oil that needs to evaporate. Air movement can facilitate getting the particles loose, and over time drive down the smell.
Hypothesis: the drawers' wood has some oils/tanins/mold/something that smells, and ventilation may draw out the substance reducing or eliminating the smell.

Personally, I would try first airing it out and cleaning it, then if necessary one of the enzyme odor cancelers available from pet stores. Those are discussed in more detail on pets.se, and they do work if brought in contact with the source of the odor.
If all else fails, then yes, encapsulating it under paint could be worth considering.
